# Horizontally flipping .getUserMedia's Webcam image stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

So I have been messing with this page: https://tutorialzine.github.io/pwa-photobooth/

Basically what it does is activate your webcam and lets you take a snapshot directly from the stream, I borrowed this for my web but the video stream is flipped and I want to mirror the video stream so it feels better.

Note: I am kind of a js newbie so an in depht explanation would be welcomed.

Here is the code, you MAY have to use Firefox instead of Chrome:

```js
$('.closecam').click(function(){
    $('.webcam__overlay').hide();
    });
 
  $('.camera').click(function(){
    $('.webcam__overlay').show();
    });
 
 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // References to all the element we will need.
    var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),
        image = document.querySelector('#snap'),
        start_camera = document.querySelector('#start-camera'),
        controls = document.querySelector('.controls'),
        take_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#take-photo'),
        delete_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#delete-photo'),
        download_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#download-photo'),
        error_message = document.querySelector('#error-message');


    // The getUserMedia interface is used for handling camera input.
    // Some browsers need a prefix so here we're covering all the options
    navigator.getMedia = ( 
        navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia
    );


    if(!navigator.getMedia){
        displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
    }
    else{
        // Request the camera.
        navigator.getMedia(
            {
                video: true
            },
            // Success Callback
            function(stream) {

                // Create an object URL for the video stream and
                // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

                // Play the video element to start the stream.
                video.play();
                video.onplay = function() {
                    showVideo();
                };
         
            },
            // Error Callback
            function(err) {
                displayErrorMessage("There was an error with accessing the camera stream: " + err.name, err);
            }
        );
    }



    // Mobile browsers cannot play video without user input,
    // so here we're using a button to start it manually.
    start_camera.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Start video playback manually.
        video.play();
        showVideo();

    });


    take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        //prevents default behaviour, in this case the link a from firing
        e.preventDefault();

        var snap = takeSnapshot();

        // Show image. 
        image.setAttribute('src', snap);
        image.classList.add("visible");

        // Enable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");

        // Set the href attribute of the download button to the snap url.
        download_photo_btn.href = snap;

        // Pause video playback of stream.
        video.pause();

    });


    delete_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Hide image.
        image.setAttribute('src', "");
        image.classList.remove("visible");

        // Disable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");

        // Resume playback of stream.
        video.play();

    });



    function takeSnapshot() {
        // Here we're using a trick that involves a hidden canvas element.  

        var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
            context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

        var width = video.videoWidth,
            height = video.videoHeight;

        if (width && height) {

            // Setup a canvas with the same dimensions as the video.
            hidden_canvas.width = width;
            hidden_canvas.height = height;

            // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

            // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
            return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        }
    }


    function showVideo() {
        hideUI();
        video.classList.add("visible");
        controls.classList.add("visible");
    }


    function displayErrorMessage(error_msg, error) {
        error = error || "";
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        }

        error_message.innerText = error_msg;

        hideUI();
        error_message.classList.add("visible");
    }

   
    function hideUI() {
        // Helper function for clearing the app UI.

        controls.classList.remove("visible");
        start_camera.classList.remove("visible");
        video.classList.remove("visible");
        snap.classList.remove("visible");
        error_message.classList.remove("visible");
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webcam__overlay">
  <div class="webcam__maincontainer" style="width:1300px; height:580px; ; flex:0 0 auto; display:flex; flex-flow:row; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start;">
    <div class="videowebcam" style="flex:0 0 97%; ">
   <div class="" style=" height:87%; width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
     <a href="#" style="display:none;" id="start-camera" class="visible">Touch here to start the app.</a>
        <video style="min-width:640px; max-width:640px; min-height:480px; max-height:480px;" muted id="camera-stream"></video>
        <img style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:-1; width:1px; height:1px;" id="snap">
     <canvas style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:-1; width:1px; height:1px;"></canvas>
        <p style="display:none;" id="error-message"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="controls" style=" height:13%; width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:space-around; align-items:center;">
     <a href="" class="tooltip3"><img id="delete-photo" class="disabled hoveref" src="images/backcam.png" style="transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);   flex:0 0 auto; "><span data-en="Take Another" data-es="Tomar otra"class="tooltiptext3">Tomar Otra</span></a>
  <a href="" class="tooltip3"><img id="take-photo" class="hoveref" src="images/takephoto.png" style=" width:65px; height:65px;  flex:0 0 auto; "><span data-es="Tomar Foto" data-en="Take Snapshot" class="tooltiptext3">Tomar Foto</span></a>
  <a href="" id="download-photo" download="selfie.png" class="disabled tooltip3"><img class="hoveref" src="images/download2.png" style="transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);" ><span data-es="Descargar Foto" data-en="Download Snapshot"class="tooltiptext3">Descargar Foto</span></a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <span class="closecam" style="cursor:pointer; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; flex:0 0 3%; text-align:center;  font-size:25px; font-weight:600; ">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 76):

CSS trick worked perfectly:

```
video {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this also flip the video controls if using the native video controls.

Comment: Due to Firefox's decision to ignore WC3 spec for disablePictureInPicture, this method now renders the video element with backwards tooltips and looses it's flipped state when in Picture-In-Picture mode.

Comment: Three problems: 1. all the controls are flipped as well (you need to flip them once more using pseudo selector) – 2. The flip disabled when going into fullscreen mode (still looking for a workaround) – 3. flip also disabled when using picture-in-picture (also looking for a workaround)

Answer (score 11):

Check this link http://christianheilmann.com/2013/07/19/flipping-the-image-when-accessing-the-laptop-camera-with-getusermedia/

This is a functional example of an horizontal flipped video played on a canvas.

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    ctx.translate(video.videoWidth, 0);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  });

  video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this; //cache
    (function loop() {
      if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 300); // drawing at 30fps
      }
    })();
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="theater">
  <video id="video" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv" controls="false"></video>
  <br/>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <label>
          <br />Try to play me :)</label>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Despite being more code, this solution has actually been made most useful by Firefox's new Picture-In-Picture mode which is forced upon all video elements and does not allow disablePictureInPicture attribute. Transforming video elements also mirrors the Firefox UI and makes for an unreadable message as well as an unflipped video feed when broken out into the floating window.

Comment: Although, you should use requestAnimationFrame to render.

Comment: is 30 fps or 300 fps?
setTimeout(loop, 1000 /300 ); // drawing at 30fps

Comment: `setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 300)` is indeed 300fps and you should indeed use `const loop = () => { /* ... */; requestAnimationFrame(loop); }); loop();`

Answer (score 1):

This flips the camera video dynamically:

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <video id="video" autoplay></video><br>
    <button id="flip">flip</button>

    <script>

        var video   = document.getElementById ( "video" );
        var flip    = document.getElementById ( "flip" );

        // Get access to the camera!
        if ( navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ( { video: true } ).then ( function ( stream ) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
            });
        }

        // Flip video
        var flipped = false;
        flip.onclick = function() {
            var factor = flipped ? "1" : "-1";
            video.style.webkitTransform = "scaleX(" + factor + ")"; 
            video.style.transform       = "scaleX(" + factor + ")";
            flipped = !flipped;
        };

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```