# html 5 flip video horizontally without affecting the controls

Tags: html

In HTML 5, I am using [`getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to get a stream for the web cam, then I add it to the `<video>` object source.

But the video stream does not display as I expected, it needs to be mirrored/flipped horizontally.

Using a CSS on the `<video>`, also flips the controls of the video, which is not what I want.

How can the video stream be mirrored\flipped horizontally without effecting the `<video>` controls?

- Does it require a canvas as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803856?
- If does require a `<canvas>`, then how can the `<video>` controls be shown on the canvas?
- If it does not require a `<canvas>`, then how can the video stream be flipped?

Comment: If you want to do this, you will need to build separated controls and style them yourself ..  Anything applied to the `<video>` element will also be applied to the controls in HTML5 -- Something like [THIS TUTORIAL](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) May come in handy.

Comment: @Zak Thanks. I just want to flip the video so when looking on the screen it will feels like looking in the mirror. It is totally strange that the player and controls are already builtin in the browser but I need to add my own implementation for these just to mirror the video stream

Comment: There might be a JS work around you can do . But any style you put on the `video` tag is going to apply to anything "inside" it --  Including HTML5's controls ..

Comment: @Zak I know. Mentioned It in my post.